# How to specialize a generic type in object literal?

Tags: typescript

```js
// a.ts
interface Config {
    selector?: <T>(httpResponse: HttpResponse<T>) => unknown;
}

export function factory(options: Config): something {
    // use options to return something
}

// another file b.ts
// I have a type for res only here(b.ts), and I want to use it to specialize type T

import { factory } from 'a.ts';

factory({
    selector: res => res.data.data; // error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'T'
});
```

My question is: How to pass a specified type in the config object literal, so that generic type T can be specialized?

Comment: You can replace <T> with <any> not and ideal but it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `factory` to generic function, and we can pass "T" of `factory` to `Config` what also is a generic object.

Start from `Config` interface, make it become generic interface.

```
interface Config<T> { // Generically for whole interface
    selector?: (httpResponse: HttpResponse<T>) => unknown;
}
```

The next, `factory` function:

```
export function factory<T>(options: Config<T>): something { // return type is "T" or something ?
    // use options to return something
}
```

We pass type "T" from `factory` to `Config`.

Finally, an example:

b.ts

```
export type ApiResponse = {
    data: {
        username: string;
    }
}
```

Usage of factory

```
factory<ApiResponse>({
    selector: res => res.data.data.username, // typehint for the `res`, I try with HttpResponse is AxiosResponse
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your exact use case is but you can add the type to your interface like this:

```
interface Config<T> {
  selector?: (httpResponse: T) => unknown;
}

function factory(options: Config<{ data: { data: string } }>) {
  // use options to return something
  return options;
}

factory({
  selector: (res) => res.data.data,
});
```

Comment: What if I don't know the type `{data: {data: string}}` until I call `factory` function?